# Paramquery grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using param query grid , I'm getting issue in J's lib file if I add disable and enable PQ grid like below.

```
$id.pgGrid("option","disabled",true);
$id.pgGrid("option", "disabled",false);
```

On click, I'm calling methods the above code. It is working fine for me but after that when I try to destroy and initialize the grid, it is destroying but not able to initialize the grid again, catching  exception in js lib file.

```
$id.pgGrid('destroy');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add what programming language you're using to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: We are using param query grid, jQuery and bootstrap